# How would I consolidate these CSS classes?

Tags: css

I have:

```
.leftColumnContent h1 {
    font-size:22px;
    margin:0;
    text-align: left;
}
```

-and-

```
img.mediaright {
    max-width: 30% !important;
    width: 30% !important;
}
img.medialeft {
    max-width: 30% !important;
    width: 30% !important;
}
```

How would I reduce the duplication with the img.* style and include it in the .leftColumnContent class?

Comment: What is the relation between these two in your DOM?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what are you looking for?
Maybe include some images or graphics explaining what is your expected result.

Comment: The most simplistic answer is "highlight the code in `img.mediaright`. Press Ctrl+X (or your OS's equivalent). Place the cursor inside the ruleset of the `leftColumnContent` class. Press Ctrl+V. Delete the `img.medialeft` ruleset shown." But that would just be telling you how to use your IDE. What are you trying to do?